# IBOutlets are connected in Storyboard and are equal to nil (null pointer error)

Tags: ios, swift, null, fatal-error, iboutlet

I connected an `IBOutlet` called taskTableView that inherits from `UITableView!` When I run my code and hit the "done" button on the keyboard (return key) crashes the app and says, `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.` I looked down in the console and found that my `UITableView` `IBOutlet` was `nil`. Why is this and how can I solve this?

[Click To See My Code!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1s56.png)

What I've already tried:

Making it and optional instead of force unwrapping it
Reconnecting the IBOutlets

Thanks! Hope someone can help!

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code. Pictures can't be referenced or search. Please [edit] your question and copy and paste (as text) your code into the question. Point out the line causing the error. Show how this view controller is being created.

Comment: How did you present this view controller?  Is it the initial view controller in your app?  If not, how did it get shown (show code).  Is the `@IBOutlet` showing a filled-in circle next to it?  If not, double check the connection in Interface Builder.

Comment: This is not the initial view controller. I have a segue from a UIBarButtonItem to the ViewController with the text field with the "Done" button on it.

Comment: Show your code where you have declared tableview object.

Comment: I added it in through the storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Did you delete your table view?
Did you replace it with a new one?

I know that xcode can be a bit unprecise when you drag an item to create an IBOutlet.
Make sure, you selected properly your tableview before linking it up to your swift file.
Also, make shure your linking is still good by going to the last column of the right menu.
When you drag your item to the swift file to make a new IBoutlet, make shure it is the right class.

Sorry if my english isn't good, i'm from canada.

Comment: I dragged the IBOutlet to a UIViewController class. I double checked and made sure that the connection was from the UITableView and the code. It is so the connection is good.

Comment: Maybe, it is a problem with the class already set in the interface builder.